# GameObject property value not resetting on game restart

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties

**Overview**
Consider a simple coin collecting game. There are two scripts, `CollectableItem` and `ItemVault`. The `CollectableItem` has a `value` property which tells the item's worth and it is added to the `coin` prefab. The `ItemVault` has a `CurrentAmount` property which stores the total value of collected coins and it is added to the `player` prefab.

**Problem**
The value of **CurrentAmount** property of **ItemVault** object does not reset on game restart inside Unity Editor.

**Code**

*CollectableItem.cs*

```
public class CollectableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float value = 1f;
    public ItemVault vault;

    private ItemVault m_vault;

    void Start()
    {
        m_vault = vault.GetComponent<ItemVault>();
        Debug.Log(m_vault.CurrentAmount); //Does not reset
    }

    //isTrigger
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(vault != null)
        {
            m_vault.ChangeAmountBy(this.value);
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

*ItemVault.cs*

```
public class ItemVault : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float startingAmount; // 0

    public float CurrentAmount { get; private set; }

    void Start()
    {
        CurrentAmount = startingAmount;
        Debug.Log(CurrentAmount); // 0
    }

    public void ChangeAmountBy(float amount)
    {
        CurrentAmount += amount;
        Debug.Log(CurrentAmount); // CurrentAmount does not reset
    }
}
```

**Note**

1. Both `CollectableItem` and `ItemVault` are added to `prefabs`.
2. The `Start` function of `ItemVault` does log the value of `CurrentAmount` as `0` but the `Start` function of `CollectableItem` logs the last value of `CurrentAmount` in previous run.
3. Restarting the editor itself resets the value.
4. I've tried changing the `Script Execution Order` to call `ItemVault` before `CollectableItem`
5. Instantiating the properties in `Awake()` instead of `Start()` is giving the same results

Comment: By *prefabs* you mean actual **prefabs** (= ASSETS)  or INSTANCES of these **in the Scene**? And by *game restart* you mean exiting and entering PlayMode or do you have some restart functionality in your scene?

Comment: note also that `vault` and `m_vault` are redundant ... you already have an `ItemVault` reference so there is no need/use of calling `GetComponent<ItemVault>()` on it again

Comment: @derHugo Yes by prefabs I mean `Assets` and by game restart I mean exiting and entering Play mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

Make sure in `_vault` you are actually referencing an existing object reference **in the scene**, not a prefab asset - otherwise, yes you will be executing the method on the prefab instead which will not be reset on Scene load / Exiting PlayMode.

You can confirm that by starting PlayMode and then in the Hierarchy click once on the `vault` slot in the Inspector. This will highlight the referenced object either in the Hierarchy (expected) or in the Assets (should not happen!).

---

If this didn't help then your problem might be a timing issue.

If your `CollectableItem.Start` is executed **before** `ItemVault.Start` got its chance to execute you might see different values.

I usually go with the thumb-rule

- `Awake`: Initialize yourself, so anything that does not depend on others
- `Start`: Now access values of other components which have already been initialized in Awake

So In your case I would do

```
public class CollectableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float value = 1f;

    // In general rather already reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private ItemVault _vault;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Ass fallback get it on runtime
        if(!_vault) _vault = vault.GetComponent<ItemVault>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(_vault.CurrentAmount);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(_vault)
        {
            _vault.ChangeAmountBy(this.value);
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ItemVault : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    [SerializeField] private float startingAmount; // 0

    public float CurrentAmount { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        CurrentAmount = startingAmount;
        Debug.Log(CurrentAmount);
    }

    public void ChangeAmountBy(float amount)
    {
        CurrentAmount += amount;
        Debug.Log(CurrentAmount);
    }
}
```

Comment: I initialised the variables in Awake() function, still getting the old values in `Awake()` of `CollectableItem`.

Comment: I've also tried to change the script execution order via Unity editor project settings to call the `ItemVault.cs` before `CollectableItem.cs`, still no luck

Comment: as you see I said you should debug the value in `Start` not in `Awake` since it is possible that in `CollectableItem.Awake` the value is simply not initialized yet

Comment: That's what I'm doing ;-) I tried both ways actually. Same result. Plus the `ChangeAmountBy(float)` function also gives the old value each time, which makes me wonder if the problem is with the `vault` reference I'm passing through the inspector.

Comment: Again: Are you absolutely sure you are referencing the correct instances? Or are you still referencing a **Prefab** in the `vault` slot? If so then you are changing values of a prefab which is ofcourse not reset on exit playmode ...

Comment: Actually no! The `ItemVault` component is added to a `prefab`.

Comment: Well then you are altering the prefab ... this is never reset. When restarting the Editor you just didn't save ;) Make sure you only reference components of objects in the scene ... or in other words: Why are you referencing a prefab there?

Comment: So... the coins are actually prefab. Therefore, `CollectableItem` is added to a prefab. And I can't reference an instance to a prefab field, therefore `ItemVault` has to be in a prefab too

Comment: @Chaitanya It either has to be in the same prefab then or you will have to get a reference to an existing instance in the Scene! (E.g. using `FindObjectOfType`) You should never change prefab values on runtime ... because it leads to exactly the issue you have now ;)